# I would like to run some JavaScript from Grunt - how can I do so?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

This sounds like a stupid question, so apologies in advance.

I would like to simply run some JavaScript as part of a grunt build process. How can I do this?

I would like to run the JavaScript inside the NodeJS process used by Grunt to read in a file, run some logic, perform some network activity and then write a file to the filesystem, and then continue on with the Grunt task sequence.

This could look something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('myTask', [
  'runSomeJavaScript',
  'runAnotherGruntTask'
]);
```

Comment: can you give some more info, do you mean like a node command line tool? what would the javascript do and what would be the runtime?

Comment: I would like to run the JavaScript inside the NodeJS process used by Grunt to read in a file, run some logic, perform some network activity and then write a file to the filesystem, and then continue on with the Grunt task sequence.

Comment: Why not create your own NodeJS module?

Comment: @evolutionxbox My own full blown separate grunt task? I wanted something lighter-weight.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for is light-weight. The answer given by @jgillich is the lightest-weight way of implementing a task as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `grunt.registerTask()` and pass at least a name and a function.

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', 'A sample task that logs stuff.', function(arg1, arg2) {
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    grunt.log.writeln(this.name + ", no args");
  } else {
    grunt.log.writeln(this.name + ", " + arg1 + " " + arg2);
  }
});
```

http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks